# What does this differential form mean?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-theorem, differential-operators

On a comment to my [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828211/1094230) answer,
there is a comment where this expression is written:

> $$\frac{1}{n^n} \left(p\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}p}\right)^k \left(q\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}q}\right)^{n-k} (p+q)^n \Bigg|_{q=1-p}$$

What does it mean?  I've never seen differential operators in binomial/combinatorics context before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition
\begin{align}
\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right) u &= q\frac{du}{dq},
\\
\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^2 u &= q\frac{d}{dq}\left(q\frac{du}{dq}\right)
=q\frac{du}{dq}+q^2\frac{d^2 u}{dq^2},
\\
\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^3 u &=
q\frac{d}{dq}\left(\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^2 u\right)
=
q\frac{du}{dq}+3q^2\frac{d^2u}{dq^2}+q^3\frac{d^3 u}{dq^3},
\end{align}
and, recursively,
$$
\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^{n+1} u = \left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)\left(q\frac{d}{dq}\right)^{n} u
$$